# Automatically connect to another Wi-Fi is there is no Internet

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Is there a way to make Windows automatically switch to another Wi-Fi network is the current one does no longer have an *Internet* connection?

My computer is in a large student dormitory like complex, where some networks sometimes stop working. I would like my computer to always be online even if I'm not there.

Comment: @CheesusCrust that would only switch if the WiFi network itself went down. If that WiFi network stays up, yet isn't routing to the Internet, the device isn't going to switch to another network.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Ah, I misread.  Thank you for clearing that up.  I will remove my comment.

Comment: I don't believe there is any software that does this, but you can definitely accomplish this in powershell.

Comment: Which Windows version?

Comment: Windows 10 1703